# how to convert angular js dynamic array into php array and submit array values into new php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, angularjs

can anybody suggest me how to convert angular js dynamic array into php array and then submit value of php array in any new file. in my program i am working in arraytest.php and want to send php array in saveform.php in php format. please anybody help me to do this. thanks

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myform" action="saveform.php" method="post">
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl" data-ng-init="input.var1=input.var2=''"> 
  <div ng-repeat="input in inputs" >
    <input type="text" value="254" ng-model= "input.var1"/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="input.var2"/>
   <button type='button' ng-click='remove(input)'>Remove</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type='button' ng-click='add()'>Add</button>
  </div>
     <p style="display:none">TotalDays = {{getTotal(value)}}</p><br><br>
     <div ng-repeat="dateTimeList in myarray">
            <!--  first value:  <input type ="text" value="{{ fir_value = dateTimeList.first }}">
              second value:   <input type ="text" value="{{ sec_value = dateTimeList.second }}">-->
              <p>{{ fir_value = dateTimeList.first }}</p>
              <p>{{ sec_value = dateTimeList.second }}</p>
                <?php 
                 $array1 = array("{{fir_value}}","{{sec_value}}"); 
                 print_r($array1); 
                ?>

     </div>

     <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</div>



<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.inputs = [{}]; // default 1 sets

  $scope.add = function()
   {
    $scope.inputs.push({});
   }

  $scope.getTotal = function(a)
   {


        var total = 0,first_value=0,second_value=0, total2 = 0;
        $scope.myarray = [{}];
      angular.forEach($scope.inputs, function(value) 
      { // loop over array to process all items
            first_value = value.var1;
            second_value = value.var2;
            $scope.myarray.push({first:first_value,second:second_value});
      });
return total;

  }

// coding for remove button
  $scope.remove = function(item) {
    angular.forEach($scope.inputs, function(value, key) {
      if (value == item) {
        $scope.inputs.splice(key, 1);
      }
    });
  }
});
</script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is another file saveform.php

```
<?php
echo "output of array is:- ";
extract($_POST);
if(isset($submit))
{
print_r($arr);
}
?>
```

plnkr demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/20PLT52Ia86UyGClQh7h?p=preview

Comment: **Dont use extract** like that to imitate the old and **insecure** way PHP used to work. Use the `$_POST['xxx']` array directly plus all data in $_POST needs to be cleansed and verified.

Comment: actual problem is, that i am not able to create array in php, extracting an array is the second step.

Comment: `$_POST` is an array!!! `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: $array1 = array("{{fir_value}}","{{sec_value}}"); 
this line is not doing its work.... $array1 doesnt hold array values. why ??

Comment: i think $_POST is not an array in my case.

Comment: can i expect anybody to help me ??

Comment: Do a google search for `angular $_POST` and you will find a number of SO questions and answers as well as some offsite ones.

Comment: am still searching my answer..how to post dynamic generated angular array to a php file ? as i will get my answer,i will mark that answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**First at all:**

You are mixing AngularJS and php but you cant use AngularJS expression in php.

Your code:

```
<p>{{ fir_value = dateTimeList.first }}</p>
<p>{{ sec_value = dateTimeList.second }}</p>
<?php
$array1 = array("{{fir_value}}","{{sec_value}}");
print_r($array1);
?>
```

will be parsed into this:

```
<p>{{ fir_value = dateTimeList.first }}</p>
<p>{{ sec_value = dateTimeList.second }}</p>
array("{{fir_value}}","{{sec_value}}")
```

And then is AngularJS called. If that is what you want, okay.

*by the way, you are closing the bottom scripttag twice*

**Submitting Forms:**

AngularJS will submit forms as `json` via the `$http` service and not as key/value pairs like normal forms.
If you want to receive this data with php you have to read the input stream like this:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
```

`$request` will now contain the form data.